# How Extract from XMLTYPE column, corresponding label for value in a tag within a value/label list from same XML

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, extract, xmltype

I got a sql from an Oracle table with a XMLTYPE column.
The Xml has a tag  with a value '2' and in the same xml there is the list with value/label pairs like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <characteristics>
        <motor>
            <fuel>2</fuel>
        </motor>
    </characteristics>
    <ValuesList>
        <CarValues>
            <CarValue>
                <value>1</value>
                <label>Diesel</label>
            </CarValue>
            <CarValue>
                <value>2</value>
                <label>Unleaded petrol</label>
            </CarValue>
        </CarValues>
    </ValuesList>
</Root>
```

With `extract()` or `extractValue()` functions it's easy to get the value for  tag with any of these staments a, b

```
SELECT extract(t.xmlColumn, '//fuel/text()').getStringVal() a,
       extractValue(t.xmlColumn, '//fuel') b
  FROM Table t
```

The problem is I want to get the label text for value '2' from Valueslist 'Unleaded petrol'

I try to get that value with a XPATH expresion like this:

```
extractValue(t.xmlColumn, '//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel]')
```

The XPATH has been evaluated with Notepad XML Tools and it works, but there's no way to get any result. it's always null.

Any idea how to achive this? I don't know how to use XMLTABLE or any other solution to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `/text()` part in your attempt:

```
SELECT
extract(t.xmlColumn,'//fuel/text()').getStringVal() a
,extractValue(t.xmlColumn,'//fuel') b
,extractValue(t.xmlColumn, '//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel/text()]') c
FROM your_table t
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | Unleaded petrol |

In your version you're trying to match a label with a value of the node `<fuel>2</fuel>`, not the text within than node, `2`.

Both `extract()` and `extractValue()` are deprecated, so you could use XMLQuery instead:

```
SELECT
XMLQuery('//fuel/text()' passing xmlColumn returning content) a
,XMLQuery('//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel/text()]/text()' passing xmlColumn returning content) a
FROM your_table t
```

| A | A |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Unleaded petrol |

Or with XMLTable();

```
SELECT x.a, x.b
FROM your_table t
CROSS APPLY XMLTable(
  '/'
  passing t.xmlColumn
  columns a number path '//fuel',
    b varchar2(30) path '//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel/text()]'
) x
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Unleaded petrol |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pxDV3rkA)

---

If your version of Oracle isn't working with the node traversal using `../` then you could do it the hard way by getting the fuel value and all the id/label pairs with separate XMLTable calls, and then filtering those that match:

```
SELECT x1.fuel, x2.label
FROM your_table t
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '//fuel'
  passing t.xmlColumn
  columns fuel number path '.'
) x1
JOIN XMLTable(
  '//CarValue'
  passing t.xmlColumn
  columns value number path 'value',
    label varchar2(30) path 'label'
) x2 ON x2.value = x1.fuel
```

| FUEL | LABEL |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Unleaded petrol |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-n5x1XzU)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to include the /text() part in all combinations; '//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel/text()]', '//CarValue/label[../value/text()=//fuel/text()]', '//CarValue/label[../value=//fuel/text()]/text()' and still doesn't work.
I've also tried your other two solutions 
I got to add  .getStringVal() to get 2 with XMLQuery
I don't get 3rd working

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can see it working in the db<>fiddle, with the first one of those and `extractValue()`, `XMLQuery()` or `XMLTable()`. The second is wrong but the third also works with `extract()`, which you shouldn't really be using any more. But yes, you might need `getStringVal()` for the XMLQuery one, depending on your client. The XMLQuery generates numbers and string though, so that should just work as-is anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I seem to remember some issues with walking back up the XML tree with `..` in an older version. Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Alex Poole thanks again. Your answer is very helpful and instructive.  I've tried extractValue(), XMLQuery() and XMLTable() methods, but unfortunately with same result, I get the value but not the label.
I'm using Oracle Developer  Versión 22.2.1.234 if it helps.
I believe your answers are right but I guess I miss something with XPATH or may be the issue walking back up the XML tree with .. and I haven't skills or enough resources to work it out.

Comment: I've reproduce in db<>fiddle  your answers in a short cut version of my  larger xml with my own tags names and it works fine. i get same results as yours.
So I guess you were right and it's an issue with Oracle Dev interpreting xpath. thanks so much!

Comment: @Goyo - I meant the version of Oracle (`select * from v$version`), not the version of your client. I think the problem I vaguely recall was on 11g, but you can't be on something that old if `cross apply` isn't erroring. Anyway... I've added an alternative approach that might work for you.

Comment: My versión is "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.13.0.0.0"
I can't believe it! Your new solution works on fiddle. I translate it  with other tags names and it also works on fiddle 
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/JqoIzLWZ)
But,  on my client it only works the first part and not the second one, and only after adding 'LEFT' to second JOIN XMLTable. Result is null otherwise.
Well, I guess I'll take a workaround after extraction finally. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Goyo - everything in your fiddle works for me in 19.16, without changing to an outer join. I'm using SQL Developer too - 22.2.0.173 but close enough to what you're using. Can you create your fiddle table in your own database and try the query? Just in case there's still some difference in structure in your real table data (maybe a typo or an accent or a unicode replacement...).

Comment: You are right! I created the fiddle table in my own database and the queries worked perfectly, like all other solutions you gave me.
I feel a bit silly! I finally discovered the problem I had overlooked. 
As I always work with Xfa Pdf files I assumed that the Xml schema was the same but the XMLType field in the database doesn't include lists of values which are added to the pdf file when files are created.
I'll need to include an auxiliary table with these values lists during extracting.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

All solutions Alex Poole gave are accepted solutions for the question case title where "a value/label list within same XML"  is present.

Just for information, in case "a value/label list is not present in the same XML", solution is create an auxiliary XMLTable with a XMLTYPE field and the value/label list XML in it.

```
SELECT x1.fuel, x2.labelFROM your_table t
CROSS JOIN XMLTable(
  '//fuel'
  passing t.xmlColumn
  columns fuel number path '.'
) x1
LEFT JOIN XMLTable(
  '//CarValue'
  passing 
  (SELECT XMLTYPE('
    <ValuesList>
        <CarValues>
            <CarValue>
                <value>1</value>
                <label>Diesel</label>
            </CarValue>
            <CarValue>
                <value>2</value>
                <label>Unleaded petrol</label>
            </CarValue>
        </CarValues>
    </ValuesList>
  ') FROM dual)
  columns value number path 'value',
    label varchar2(30) path 'label'
) x2 ON x2.value = x1.fuel
```